# Can I change an image on hovering over an element, without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, hover

Is it possible to do something like this except as a sprite, only using css/html?

Excuse the poor example. I am just trying to figure this out.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4tp/)

Comment: As your jsfiddle example now shows the result, could you please either put your original code here? Or fully describe what you wanted to reach? As it is now, the question is not really useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just put the two images together into one, and use the `background-position` style to change what part of the image is shown.

I applied it to your example, but I just use the top and bottom half of one of the images:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Lx4tp/2/

HTML:

```
<a class="link">Buy Now<a/>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
   width:100px;
   height:12px;
   background: #fff url('http://server2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/prettyoffice/24/add1-.png') no-repeat right 0;
   display:block;
}

.link:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    background-position: right -12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what happens if there are other images in the sprite? In your example you the size of the background image is 100 by 12 so what if there are 4 more image on the x axis wont they show up? Like here http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4tp/4/

Comment: @Jacino: You can only limit the background image with the size of the element, so if you have more images horisontally in the sprite, you have to make the element as wide as the part that you want to show. You can put a span tag inside the link, and make both the link and the span tag block elements, then you can put the image as background in the span so that the link can be larger than the image.

Comment: Ahhh i see what you mean now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a hover or something more?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover

Comment: I am trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx4tp/ except with sprites instead of individual images.

Comment: Taek a look at this link: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-sprites-wout-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a sprite. You will just need to change the background position for the hover rule.

```
.link {
   background-image: url('sprite.png');
   background-position: 0 0;
}

.link:hover {
   background-position: 0 -10px;
}
```